# Using x in a lambda expression in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, lambda, expression

This issue seems to only have creeped in in the last few weeks. When I use `x` in a lambda expression I used to be able to just do `.Where(x => x.)` and that would be fine.

But now when I do `.Where(x` and hit space it automatically puts in `ConfigXmlDocument` or `X500DistinguishedName`.

Has anyone else been experiencing this issue? If this isn't the right place for this type of question I apologies.

Comment: Which version of C# are you on and do you have `using System.Linq` at the top of your file?

Comment: Yes I do have Linq imported to the file. I think I found the reason but Im not sure yet. "We think that this might be caused by the “Show items from unimported namespaces”, which you can disable in “Tools > Options”, “Text Editor > C# > IntelliSense”." This seems to be a new experimental feature so it looks like it could be the issue.

Comment: I have the same issue. VERY annoying. VS 16.7.2

Answer (score 2):

Go to Tools > Options > Text Editor > C# > IntelliSense

Find and disable the option "Show items from unimported namespaces (experimental)".

This option is actually very interesting as it will find out quickly classes and add the `using` automatically when you are typing, but when writing a lambda expression it is very annoying that it doesn't default to `x` or whatever variable you use.

Comment: Thank you!  This was absolutely killing me and fixed the issue perfectly.

Comment: For me it was unticking the "Automatically show completion list in arguments list (expirmental)" option.  But this post pointed me to the right spot.  So thanks, thumbs up :)